# Non-zero tensor becomes 0 after sending to device [PyTorch]

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to test my CNN, but I am finding that the batch of testing images I send to the GPU seems to become all zeroes. Here is the number of non-zero items within the tensor before and after being sent to the GPU.

```
tensor(319845)
tensor(0, device='mps:0')
```

The only difference between these two lines of code is in one case, the batch is not sent `.to(device)`, and in the other, it is. Here is my test method in total:

```
def test():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(test_X), BATCH_SIZE)):
        print(test_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 100, 100).count_nonzero())
        batch_X = test_X[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].view(-1, 1, 100, 100).to(device)
        print(batch_X.count_nonzero())
        batch_y = test_y[i:i+BATCH_SIZE].to(device)
        
        batch_out = net(batch_X)
        # print(batch_out)
        out_maxes = [torch.argmax(i, axis=0) for i in batch_out]

        target_maxes = [torch.argmax(i) for i in batch_y]

        for i,j in zip(out_maxes, target_maxes):
            if i == j:
                correct += 1
            total += 1
        break
    print(correct, total)
    print("Accuracy: ", round(correct/total, 3))
```

If it is relevant, it is worth noting that I am using the M1 GPU for this task and thus not using a stable PyTorch release, but the preview release at this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the exact code you used and the exact pytorch version

Comment: I don't seem to be facing this issue on PyTorch version 1.8+cu111, here are my outputs using the same code that you have above -- tensor(40000) on CPU, and tensor(40000, device='cuda:0') after sending it to the device. Can you list the exact PyTorch version that you are using?